# Share immunity by kissing?

Tags: immunity, influenza

How can you get a cold by kissing someone who already has it, but you can't get their antibodies by kissing them after they recover? Or can you?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: Some questions to ask yourself: What are antibodies and where are they found? What causes colds and how are they spread? From the answers to these basic questions you should be able to see that the answer to your question is relatively straightforward ...

Answer (score 0):

Antibodies are in the blood, not in the saliva, whereas herpes virus is secreted to saliva so you get infected through the contact with mucosa.